# Tetrad formalism: Cartesian-like tetrad?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

I'm confused about tetrad formalism.
In the [article](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1972ApJ...178..347B/abstract) the have the Kerr metric in Boyler-Lindquist coordinates. They then define the tetrad at a point $r,t,\theta,\varphi$ as the one-form basis
$$
e^{(t)} = \left(\frac{\Sigma \Delta}{A}\right)^{1/2} dt
$$
$$
e^{(r)} = \left(\frac{\Delta}{\Sigma}\right)^{1/2} dr
$$
$$
e^{(\theta)} = \Sigma^{1/2} d\theta
$$
$$
e^{(\varphi)} = - \frac{2 M a r \sin \theta}{(\Sigma A)^{1/2}} dt + \left(\frac{A}{\Sigma}\right)^{1/2} \sin\theta \; d\varphi
$$
along with the dual basis $e_{(t)}, e_{(r)}, e_{(\theta)}, e_{(\varphi)}$. If we denote this as $e_{(i)} = e^\mu _{(i)} \partial_{x^\mu}$, we can write that
$$
g_{\mu\nu}e^{\mu}_{(a)} e^{\nu}_{(b)} = \eta_{(a)(b)}
$$
where $\eta_{(a)(b)} = diag({-1,1,1,1})$.

Now I'm confused about this. I thought that if we have the "Minkowski metric" $\eta_{(a)(b)}$. Every vector in the tetrad should be expressed (locally) in a cartesian way. That is, if we have some tensor $T^{\alpha}$ we could say that
$$
T^{(a)} = \{T^t, T^z, T^x,T^y\}
$$
where
$$
T^{(a)} = T^\alpha e_\alpha^{(a)}.
$$
But when I did the calculation for some explicit vector (think electric field) this doesn't seem right.

So the equestion is: How do I define the same tetrad, such that the tetrad basis is (locally) Minkowski - meant in the Cartesian Minkowski way?

Phrased in another way how do I find the tetrad basis $e_{(t)},e_{(z)}, e_{(x)}, e_{(y)}$ with respect to Boyer-Lindquist cooridnates.

Edit: I did't write Boyer-Lindquist coordinate nor the metric, please refer to the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)